# Append shell-command output to named buffer

Tags: init-file, shell-command

In my init file I have a function that runs a `shell-command` everytime I open emacs. I rarely need to look at the out put of this command, so having it pop up in the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer every time I open emacs is unnecessary, and also means that I always have to take an extra step to get rid of that window.

From the documentation for `shell-command`, I have learned that I can provide an `OUTPUT-BUFFER` argument and direct the output where I want it to go. Sending it to the `*Messages*` buffer is almost the perfect solution for me, because it means I don't need to think about the output of the script, but if I do need to find it, I can find it in `*Messages*`, which seems to be a logical place to look for it.

My only problem is that adding the `OUTPUT-BUFFER` argument will make it so that whatever messages are in the `*Messages*` buffer at the time the command is run will be replaced by the `shell-command` output. I rarely look at the `*Messages*` buffer unless I need to, but I want to make sure I don't remove anything important just in case. Is there any way for me to append the output of `shell-command` to this buffer rather than replacing the buffer's contents? Any push in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to put the output of a command into the `*Messages*` buffer.

```
(defun my-shell-command-to-message (command)
  "Run a command in the shell and append its output to the *Messages* buffer."
  (message (shell-command-to-string command)))
```

Note that it also displays it at the bottom of the screen.

To append the output of a command to a named buffer you could use a function like `my-shell-command-to-buffer` below.

```
(defun my-shell-command-to-buffer (command buffer-name)
  "Run a `command' and append its output to buffer `buffer-name'."
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create buffer-name)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert (shell-command-to-string command))))
```